# EFCore Querying by a Null Navigation property

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

So I have a student class which has a navigation property to another table.  I simply want to query all students who are both NOT in that table and IN that table

```
var students = context.Students.Include(x => x.Exclusion);
var excluded = students.Where(x => x.Exclusion != null);
var included = students.Where(x => x.Exclusion == null);
```

Result:

- students: 9
- excluded: 9

So that's wrong... if I .ToList() students, excluded is now 2 which is correct, so I assume navigation property queries don't work in EFCore, need to be moved to in memory?

```
var students = context.Students.Include(x => x.Exclusion);
var excluded = students.ToList().Where(x => x.Exclusion != null);
var included = students.ToList().Where(x => x.Exclusion == null);
```

- students: 9
- excluded: 2
- included: 0

...How is it 0??  We can query if it's not null, but not if it IS null?

It looks like from debugging the unit test the generated sql query for *both* is pulling in just the 2 excluded items, so I assume when I then execute the == null that's why it's 0, but I have no idea why it's doing this, it's not what I'm asking it to do.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, the Type generic passed into the .HasForignKey was the issue

This is the bad one

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Student)
                        .WithOne(p => p.Exclusion)
                        .HasForeignKey<Student>(d => d.UserId)
                        .HasConstraintName("fk_exclusion_user");
```

This fixed it

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Student)
                        .WithOne(p => p.Exclusion)
                        .HasForeignKey<Exclusion>(d => d.UserId)
                        .HasConstraintName("fk_exclusion_user");
```